# wasserstein distance for multiple histograms

Tags: python, distance-matrix, earth-movers-distance

I'm trying to calculate the distance matrix between histograms. I can only find the code for calculating the distance between 2 histograms and my data have more than 10. My data is a CSV file and histogram comes in columns that add up to 100. Which consist of about 65,000 entries, I only run with 20% of the data but the code still does not work.

I've tried the **distance_matrix from scipy.spatial.distance_matrix but it ignore the face that data are histogram and treat them as normal numerical data.** I've also tried wasserstein distance but the error was `object too deep for desired array`

```
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
distance = wasserstein_distance (df3,df3)
```

I expected the result to be somewhat like this :

```
0   1              2           3           4             5          6    
0   0.000000    259.730341  331.083554  320.302997  309.577373  249.868085 
1   259.730341  0.000000    208.368304  190.441382  262.030304  186.033572  
2   331.083554  208.368304  0.000000    112.255111  256.269253  227.510879  
3   320.302997  190.441382  112.255111  0.000000    246.350482  205.346804  
4   309.577373  262.030304  256.269253  246.350482  0.000000    239.642379
```

but it was an error instead

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?It seems like the shape of `df3` is illicit, is `df3` a 1D array ?

Comment: Is there a source that even formulates multivariate Wasserstein distance? I too have only seen bivariate (2 histograms), not multivariate